# How to persist offline messages and sent to the message queue once device becomes online in android?

Tags: android, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have followed the following tutorial and created the RabbitMQ android application.

[RabbitMQ on Android](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-07-29-rabbitmq-on-android.html)

I have created both the publisher and subscriber modules and I can be able to send the messages to message queue in publisher and receive the messages from the message queue in the subscriber.

In the publisher module offline messages are sent to the message queue if the application is opened until the internet comes back. If the application is closed then the offline messages are not sent to the message queue.

I want to send the offline messages to the message queue even if the application is closed. I know we can able to store the offline messages in the local storage and sent to the message queue when the device becomes online. But I want this to be handled by the RabbitMQ Android SDK. Is is possible to handle this with RabbitMQ? If possible please give me some suggestions.

Comment: If you are open to considering other libraries, take a look at this library https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue

Comment: yeah the thing about such un - common api will be , ull never find answers, it is better to use firebase messaging which has all the solution pre enabled and and also it is free. then those crappy apis

Comment: This seems like the minimum requirement for a Message Queue system. I don't see why client-adaptors simply have an outbound queue feature built in with a backing data file.